# Pegar valores dinmamicamente com Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho um laço foreach que preenche a tela com informações dos usuarios logados no sistema, nome, tipo e ID. implementei um botão com um campo textfield para enviar mensagens para os usuarios do sistema e um botão destravar

```
var id = $(this).val();
```

A funcionalidade do botão destravar funciona perfeitamente pois só precisa pegar o id e destravar o usuario...
Como acrescentei o campo textfield e outro botão para enviar a mensagem para o id desse usuario o valor desse textField não esta dinamico como ID.
na linha :`var texto= $('#review').val();`
Já tentei aplicar o **find** o **prop** um **each** para percorrer e nada.
Queria que o campo textFild me apresente o valor dinamicamente igual ao campo id

```
$('.row').on('click', '#btn_text', function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    var texto= $('#review').val();
    const element = this;
    alert(texto + id);
});
```

o Codigo html/php é o seguinte:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                <?php
                      foreach ($logados as $usuarios) {
                          if ($usuarios['id'] != $_SESSION['user_id']){
                         echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="author-permissio-wrap shadow-reset">
                            <div class="author-per-img">
                                <a><img src="' . $usuarios['img'] .  '" alt="" />
                                </a>
                                <div class="author-per-content">
                                    <h2>' . $usuarios['nome_completo'] . '</h2>
                                    <p>'. $usuarios['tipo'] .'</p>
                                    <p><button class="btn btn-custon-four btn-primary btn-xs" id="deslogar" value="' . $usuarios['id'] . '">Destravar</button> </p>
                                    <p class="comment-clock"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>' . $usuarios['ultimo_login'] . '</p>
                                    <textarea name="review" id="review" cols="30" rows="3" ></textarea>
                                    <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-custon-four btn-default"  id="btn_text" value="' . $usuarios['id'] . '"><span class="fa fa-comment"></span></button></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
                          }
                     }
                ?>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: O atributo `id` deve ser único no `html` e alguns deles irão se repetir no seu código, como  deslogar, btn_text e review.

Answer (score 0):

Matei aqui pegando o elemento atual usando de um laço! no campo **textarea**

```
$('textarea').each(function() {
        var currentElement = $(this);
        var texto = currentElement.val(); // i
    });
```